# How to add H5P to Code Igniter or TinyMCE Editor?

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, h5p

I am stuck at the point of adding h5p interactive components to a Code Igniter (PHP) course website.
There is a TinyMCE Editor there, Now How can I add an h5p button so that I can add an interactive component?

I have tried to use h5p standalone php library but it is not what I needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there currently is a PHP based solution to what you're looking for.

If you have a look at https://snordian.de/2023/04/22/what-was-that-thing-again-an-h5p-architecture-overview/ you'll notice that the H5P framework has two separate modules for the H5P core: one for the view and one for the editor. H5P Standalone only provides the functionality to support the part of H5P core which is meant for viewing H5P content, but not for editing it (which is much more complex).

I don’t know of any other PHP based standalone solution that would offer what you need either.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Answer. I think should add a button to tinyMCE editor on-click will open a model having a form, where we can upload our downloaded .h5p content and with a library it will do like explained here https://h5p.org/creating-your-own-h5p-plugin in Uploading H5P Files section. What you think it will work? I need advice. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Stack overflow is not a platform for general advice though.